# MySQL frequently stop

Tags: mysql

My disk still has a lot of space, so it's not the memory problem.

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/vda1             55G         17G        36G       32% /

**Here's the error log**

> 190712  7:55:45 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover
>   instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in
>   a future release. Please use the full name instead.
>
> 190712  7:55:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 190712  7:55:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 190712  7:55:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 190712  7:55:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
>
> 190712  7:55:45 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>
> 190712  7:55:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
>
> 190712  7:55:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 190712  7:55:45 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the
>   buffer pool
>
> 190712  7:55:45 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 190712  7:55:45 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE
>   ENGINE failed.
>
> 190712  7:55:45 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>
> 190712  7:55:45 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 190712  7:55:45 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

I have to restart MySQL manually

Comment: https://medium.com/@jm_c/mysql-crashing-innodb-mmap-bytes-failed-errno-12-64d5b801b2f2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR \[InnoDB\] mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167454/error-innodb-mmap137428992-bytes-failed-errno-12)

Comment: A similar issue was reported on: https://serverfault.com/a/597391/375645. The suggested solution was to remove the log files

Comment: Been doing that but it doesn't help much, i have to restore the backup several days ago.

Comment: @NadirLatif removing log files doesn't help an out of memory problem. It does [corrupt users' data quite well however](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/318946/mariadb-doesnt-work-after-system-crash/318991#318991).